# Change default Android Emulator settings

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I am building an Android application in Xamarin. I use the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) to test the app.

When I launch the emulator I set it up to meet my needs, for example, configuring the cameras to map to my laptop's. Once it's all set up it works great.

*Screen shot of one of the configuration tabs below:*

[image: Screen shot of one of the configuration tabs below]

However, every time I restart the emulator I lose all my settings. I'd like to persist these settings to save time in future but there is no save option. I traced the Emulator settings to AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\
where there is a default config for `7_KitKat_(4.4)_XHDPI_Tablet.cfg` and `5_KitKat_(4.4)_XXHDPI_Phone.cfg`.

Inside, they look like config block pasted below. Is this the right place to change the config defaults and where can I find the list of possible settings? I have Googled extensively but keep coming up with no results or results for the similar config.ini for other emulators.

```
configuration[id]=363F7AED-462C-46BD-9FEC-F1DD3B79916C
configuration.type=device
configuration.version=1.0.60404.1
device.description=Similar to Samsung Galaxy S5, Sony Xperia Z
device.platform=6FAA28E5-6520-4516-B1A5-C7B72CAE3E31
device.screen.diagonal=5
device.screen.resolution=1080x1920
device.vm.cpu.architecture=x86
device.vm.cpu.count=4
device.vm.heap.size=192
device.vm.ram.size=2048
device.vm.vhd=vhd\\5_KitKat_(4.4)_XXHDPI_Phone\\image.vhd
device.name=5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
```

Comment: This is a bug. We recommend moving to Google Emulators with HAXM - you get set these up by running installer from http://www.xamarin.com/downloads. Make sure to disable Hyper-V.

Comment: The link you sent is broken. Can you pass through BLuetoothLE to the Google emulators?